# How to prevent VPS owner from accessing my API key

Tags: vps

I want to run a program on a vps, which uses my api key for doing financial transactions. I don't want there to be any chance the host owning the vps or any other hacker to ever be able to see my api key. Is there a way to make this impossible.

Comment: the host owning the vps will always be able to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. If you don't own the computer, you don't own the computer.

You will have to calculate the risk. Is more financially rewarding for the VPS owner to provide you with the services, or to steal your keys and your money? Is the reputation damage worth it?

Usually, the VPS owner aren't interested on your data, so if you use a reputable provider, with years of service and lots of users, you will be safe. But a no-name provider using rented servers, dead cheap price, and lack of support may not be a good place to be.

Comment: Well said.  Even if you fetch the key from another server over an encrypted channel, your VPS provider would still be able to read the (plaintext) key in the RAM of your VPS, because it's their RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in a compiled language, like Golang, and hardcode API keys inside. It is not best practice, but Golang cannot be decompiled, and the key will be secure inside the binary.

Comment: But the API key would be in memory, and transmitted on the wire. And both of those things are controlled by the VPS owner. All you achieve in your suggestion is protection from being able to read the API from the filesystem.

Comment: There may not be any good [decompilers for go, but there's certainly tools for analyzing them](https://go-re.tk/).